# How to get a higher res image in the Login page?

Tags: macos, login-screen

For years, I've been using the 'Calico Cat' image that ships with OS X for my account.

Since upgrading to Mountain Lion (maybe since Lion?) the Login page has larger round account images, and it shows the 'Calico Cat' image as a rather stretched and fuzzy rendering.

Is there a way to fix this?  Did Apple simply not provide a higher res version of the default account images?  If not, this seems like an oversight, Apple used to be very conscious of such things, for example, I know that every application icon has an embedded hi-res version it's image.

Any suggestions are welcome.  Thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're right. The icons are just low-res, not up to snuff for how they are being rendered now. You can find them, and others, in this folder: `/Library/User Pictures/Animals`. Funny thing is, some of the icons, like the Zebra or Penguin, are much higher res. It seems Apple just added new, better icons without updating all of the old ones. However, if you were to replace the cat icon with another, higher-res icon of the exact same name, I'm sure it would replace it just fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I kind of perceive this as a sign that Apple might be ignoring some of the little details.  Attention to little details like this is one of the reasons why Apple products are great.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, sometimes Apple doesn't get around to little things like this.

Comment: @Tortilla: 'Little things'? You do understand he is talking about cats, right? :)